# UITableViewCell how to make right detail text multiple lines without moving the text on the left?

Tags: ios, text, uitableview, uilabel

I am using a standard UITableViewCell, right detail. The text on the right is 2 lines, but when I let it go to two lines the text on the left is no longer vertically centered. I tried modifying the "Align Baseline" but that didn't seem to help. Is there a simple fix for this?

EDIT: The issue is the different size text. Probably the right way to fix it is to use a custom cell with the right label adjusted so that its origin is higher up.

Don't know why they closed this question. There's no code to be shown here. You can build this in interface builder without any code whatsoever.

[image: Screenshot of the table view cell.]

Thanks

Comment: I'm having this same issue and agree that this can be completely replicated without a single line of code. I was hoping to avoid creating a custom cell with it's own class and wiring up the labels, just to get 2 lines instead of 1, but from what I can tell that might not be possible.

Comment: Yeah, I wound up creating a custom cell. Fortunately it's not that difficult and it works fine.